# pasar valor de una clase java a un jsp

Tags: java, jsp, variables

quisiera saber como puedo pasar el valor de una variable de una clase java a un jsp.

public void ValidarUsuario(String usuario, String password,HttpServletRequest request) {

```
    try {

        Connection conexion=null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticketsdetrabajo", "root", "123456");
        //creamos objeto Statement

    pst=conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, usuario);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();


    if(rs.next())
    {
        dbUsuario=rs.getString("NombreUsuarios");
        dbPass=rs.getString("Contrasena");
        if(dbUsuario.equals(usuario)&& dbPass.equals(password)) {
            HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
            login=true;

        }       
    }else {
        System.out.print("El usuario o Contraseña introducidos son erroneos");
        login=false;

    }
```

Quisiera pasar la variable login a una página jsp para redireccionar a la página solo en caso de estar registrado correctamente:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guardalo en la sesion:

```
sesion.setAttribute("login", login);
```

Y despues la recoges en jsp desde el scope de sesion:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("login") %>
```

Un saludo.

Comment: una duda, si paso
sesion.setAttribute("Apellidos", apellidos);
no me coge el segundo apellido ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto y que me aparezcan los dos?

Comment: Estas seguro de que la variable apellidos contiene los dos apellidos?

Comment: Si, cojo los apellidos de apellidos=rs.getString("Apellidos"); y he comprobado que hasta aquí me aparecen los dos apellidos

Comment: Mmmm no tengo ni idea de que te puede estar pasando, te recomiendo que habrás otra pregunta con el código para que se vea mejor y podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias. Más o menos ya lo tengo. El problema es cuando le doy a la página para atrás, ya no me coge el valor del nuevo login